# Git Pull changes into a mono-repo from another repository

Tags: git, github

I have a single git repository containing multiple projects. I have pulled these projects from different git repos using the method described here:

https://medium.com/@ayushya/move-directory-from-one-repository-to-another-preserving-git-history-d210fa049d4b

Example Repo Structure:

ProjectOne

- ProjectA
- ProjectB
- ProjectC

Now, the original git repo of ProjectA is constantly under development and I need to periodically pull in latest changes to my ProjectOne repo. I want to keep the commit history of ProjectA when pulling in changes. Does anyone here has any idea how to do it ?

Comment: The source repo(ProjectA) and destination repo (ProjectOne) have different directory structure. Wouldn't that cause a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to add `ProjectA` as a [**submodule**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of `ProjectOne`

```
cd ProjecTOne
git submodule add ProjectA /url/of/ProjectA
```

That way, a simple `git submodule update --remote` would be enough to update its content with the latest of `ProjectA`, and preserving its history.

Comment: The ProjectOne repo already exists and I can't change it using submodule

Comment: @h1990 Changing it to use submodule just means you add 4 folders, as 4 submodules: it is just an evolution.